# how to pass parameter to generator function in redux saga from jsx?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have 3 generator function first is "loginUserStart" where the actual request comes then the second one is "LoginUserAsync" which is called in the "loginUserStart" and third is api call function

so I am trying to pass the parameter from my signin component to the loginUserStart function but whenever I console.log(arguments) it is showing nothing

Code:-

**Sign-in component**

```
const login = async () => {
 arr.userEmail = "sample_email";
 arr.userPassword = "sample_password";
 console.log(arr);
 signinUserStart(arr);
};

const logSubmit = () => {
 login();
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 signinUserStart: (data) => dispatch(signinUserStart(data))
});
```

**Action file code**

```
export const signinUserStart = (data) => ({
 type: UserActionTypes.Set_SigninUser_Start,
 payload: data
})
```

**saga File code**
**API generator function code**

```
export async function fetchUser(info) {
 console.log(info);
 const email = 'Admin@gmail.com'; //sample_email
 // const passwords = info.userPassword;
 const password = 'Admin@123'; //sample_password
 try {
  const user = await axios.post("http://localhost:5050/sign", {
   data: {
     email: email,
     password: password,
   },
  });
  console.log(user);
  return user;
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   return error;
  } 
}
```

**LoginUserAsync function**

```
export function* LoginUserAsync(data) {
 console.log("in saga");
 console.log(data);
 try {
  let userInfo = yield call(fetchUser, data)
  console.log(userInfo);
  yield put(setUserId('62b1c5ee515317d42239066a')); //sample_token
  yield put(setCurrentUserName(userInfo.data.userName));
 } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
}
```

**loginUserStart function**

```
export function* loginUserStart(action) {
 console.log(action.payload);//not logging anything for showing in console
 yield takeLatest(UserActionTypes.Set_SigninUser_Start, LoginUserAsync(action));
}
```

Comment: Can you add a code with take/Every/Latest where you start the `loginUserStart` saga? Or is that a root saga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing more code, but assuming that `loginUserStart` is either root saga or started from root saga it means there is no action for it to receive.

The main issue I think is this line

```
yield takeLatest(UserActionTypes.Set_SigninUser_Start, LoginUserAsync(action));
```

In the second parameter you are calling the generator function [which is wrong](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#takelatestchannel-saga-args), instead you should be passing the saga itself (as reference).

So it should look like this:

```
yield takeLatest(UserActionTypes.Set_SigninUser_Start, LoginUserAsync);
```

This way, the Redux Saga library will then call `LoginUserAsync` when `Set_SigninUser_Start` is dispatched with first param correctly set to the action object.